# Final crack in the universe

Tags: doctor-who, time

As of the the 6th season finale, was the universe crack on the TARDIS monitor-screen thing purged after the Doctor went to June 25, 2010?

Comment: Wasn't the universe repaired after the events in [The Big Bang](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Big_Bang_%28TV_story%29)? Or did I forget something?

Comment: Heh, I'm amused that "The Doctor" edited this question

Answer (score 1):

In "The Big Bang" we see a number of cracks fixed throughout the universe.  Although we don't explicitly see the crack in the TARDIS's monitor fixing itself, the implication is that all the cracks are sealing themselves.  So yes, the crack in the monitor does get repaired.